calculate cumulative sum over month and by group as well
I first calculated monthly sum by counting IDs within a group using group-by and mutate. However, as I try to use cumsum to calculate monthly cumulative sum by group using cumsum, the data just does not look right. It would be really helpful if someone can help me. Thanks~
Assuming original data frame looks like so:



person id
company
yyyy
month




1
A
2011
January


2
A
2011
January


3
A
2011
Feburary


4
A
2011
Feburary


5
A
2011
Feburary


6
A
2011
March


7
B
2011
January


8
B
2011
January


9
B
2011
January


10
B
2011
Feburary


11
B
2011
Feburary


12
B
2011
Feburary


13
B
2011
Feburary


14
B
2011
March


15
B
2011
March


16
B
2011
April



I would like to have a final output data frame like the one below.



person id
company
yyyy
month
monthly sum
cumulative monthly sum




1
A
2011
January
2
2


2
A
2011
January
2
2


3
A
2011
Feburary
3
5


4
A
2011
Feburary
3
5


5
A
2011
Feburary
3
5


6
A
2011
March
1
6


7
B
2011
January
3
3


8
B
2011
January
3
3


9
B
2011
January
3
3


10
B
2011
Feburary
4
7


11
B
2011
Feburary
4
7


12
B
2011
Feburary
4
7


13
B
2011
Feburary
4
7


14
B
2011
March
2
9


15
B
2011
March
2
9


16
B
2011
April
1
10




Only summing the first group value
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(monthlySum = n_distinct(person.id), 
         cumulativeSum = row_number() == 1, .by = c(company, yyyy, month)) %>% 
  mutate(cumulativeSum = cumsum(if_else(cumulativeSum, monthlySum, 0)), 
    .by =c(company, yyyy))
   person.id company yyyy    month monthlySum cumulativeSum
1          1       A 2011  January          2             2
2          2       A 2011  January          2             2
3          3       A 2011 Feburary          3             5
4          4       A 2011 Feburary          3             5
5          5       A 2011 Feburary          3             5
6          6       A 2011    March          1             6
7          7       B 2011  January          3             3
8          8       B 2011  January          3             3
9          9       B 2011  January          3             3
10        10       B 2011 Feburary          4             7
11        11       B 2011 Feburary          4             7
12        12       B 2011 Feburary          4             7
13        13       B 2011 Feburary          4             7
14        14       B 2011    March          2             9
15        15       B 2011    March          2             9
16        16       B 2011    April          1            10


Thanks for the response. I have a follow up question about the time dimension of this kind of data. In the example I provided in Stack Overflow, the data was sorted by month (from old to recent) already. My actual data, however, was not sorted in that order. When I tried to apply your code to mine, the way R calculated the cumulative sum was by the order of my data (Aug, Dec, Nov, Oct). I think I can fix this quickly by sorting the data first, but I was surprised that R does not handle date variable in the natural chronical order. Is there a package to take care of this more efficiently?

The month name itself would not qualify as a proper time sequence on its own, only when it’s a date class, because sorting months can only work when they’re combined with a year. Some operations order lexicographically as per default though, e.g. joins, but this is not standardized either. I’d prefer managing that order manually anyways because that makes cases when I need special orders more accessible and makes me think about my data more closely. Afaik there’s no package that auto-sorts dates other that the obvious seq.Date.

A base R option with nested ave
transform(
    df,
    cummulative_sum = ave(
        ave(person_id * 0,
            company, yyyy, month,
            FUN = \(x) replace(x, 1, length(x))
        ),
        company, yyyy,
        FUN = cumsum
    )
)

gives
   person_id company yyyy    month cummulative_sum
1          1       A 2011  January               2
2          2       A 2011  January               2
3          3       A 2011 Feburary               5
4          4       A 2011 Feburary               5
5          5       A 2011 Feburary               5
6          6       A 2011    March               6
7          7       B 2011  January               3
8          8       B 2011  January               3
9          9       B 2011  January               3
10        10       B 2011 Feburary               7
11        11       B 2011 Feburary               7
12        12       B 2011 Feburary               7
13        13       B 2011 Feburary               7
14        14       B 2011    March               9
15        15       B 2011    March               9
16        16       B 2011    April              10


library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)


df1 %>% 
  summarise(monthly_sum = n_distinct(person_id), .by = c(company, yyyy, month)) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_sum = cumsum(monthly_sum), .by = company) %>% 
  right_join(df1, .)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(company, yyyy, month)`

#>    person_id company yyyy    month monthly_sum cumulative_sum
#> 1          1       A 2011  January           2              2
#> 2          2       A 2011  January           2              2
#> 3          3       A 2011 Feburary           3              5
#> 4          4       A 2011 Feburary           3              5
#> 5          5       A 2011 Feburary           3              5
#> 6          6       A 2011    March           1              6
#> 7          7       B 2011  January           3              3
#> 8          8       B 2011  January           3              3
#> 9          9       B 2011  January           3              3
#> 10        10       B 2011 Feburary           4              7
#> 11        11       B 2011 Feburary           4              7
#> 12        12       B 2011 Feburary           4              7
#> 13        13       B 2011 Feburary           4              7
#> 14        14       B 2011    March           2              9
#> 15        15       B 2011    March           2              9
#> 16        16       B 2011    April           1             10

Data:
read.table(text= "person_id     company     yyyy    month
1   A   2011    January
2   A   2011    January
3   A   2011    Feburary
4   A   2011    Feburary
5   A   2011    Feburary
6   A   2011    March
7   B   2011    January
8   B   2011    January
9   B   2011    January
10  B   2011    Feburary
11  B   2011    Feburary
12  B   2011    Feburary
13  B   2011    Feburary
14  B   2011    March
15  B   2011    March
16  B   2011    April", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> df1

Created on 2024-04-29 with reprex v2.0.2

df %>% 
   mutate(monthly_sum=n()*(row_number() == 1), .by = c(company, yyyy, month)) %>%
   mutate(cummulative_sum = cumsum(monthly_sum),monthly_sum = first(monthly_sum), .by = company)

   person_id company yyyy    month monthly_sum cummulative_sum
1          1       A 2011  January           2               2
2          2       A 2011  January           2               2
3          3       A 2011 Feburary           2               5
4          4       A 2011 Feburary           2               5
5          5       A 2011 Feburary           2               5
6          6       A 2011    March           2               6
7          7       B 2011  January           3               3
8          8       B 2011  January           3               3
9          9       B 2011  January           3               3
10        10       B 2011 Feburary           3               7
11        11       B 2011 Feburary           3               7
12        12       B 2011 Feburary           3               7
13        13       B 2011 Feburary           3               7
14        14       B 2011    March           3               9
15        15       B 2011    March           3               9
16        16       B 2011    April           3              10


cumsum a table and merge it to your data.
> merge(dat, 
+       with(dat, table(yyyy, month, company)) |> 
+         transform(cmsum=ave(Freq, company, FUN=cumsum), msum=Freq, Freq=NULL),
+       sort=FALSE)
   company yyyy    month id cmsum msum
1        A 2011  January  1     2    2
2        A 2011  January  2     2    2
3        A 2011 February  3     5    3
4        A 2011 February  4     5    3
5        A 2011 February  5     5    3
6        A 2011    March  6     6    1
7        B 2011  January  7     3    3
8        B 2011  January  8     3    3
9        B 2011  January  9     3    3
10       B 2011 February 10     7    4
11       B 2011 February 11     7    4
12       B 2011 February 12     7    4
13       B 2011 February 13     7    4
14       B 2011    March 14     9    2
15       B 2011    March 15     9    2
16       B 2011    April 16    10    1

So that R knows in which order you want the month names, you must first convert them as a factor with the corresponding level order. However, the latter is stored in the variable month.name. (Of course, you must first correct your typo in Feburary)
> dat <- transform(dat, month=factor(month, levels=month.name))


Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(id = 1:16, company = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), yyyy = c(2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), month = c("January", 
"January", "February", "February", "February", "March", "January", 
"January", "January", "February", "February", "February", "February", 
"March", "March", "April")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

